# Implementation of java.util.Random.nextInt

Tags: java, random

This function is from [`java.util.Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). It returns a pseudorandom `int` uniformly distributed between `0` and the given `n`. Unfortunately I did not get it.

```
public int nextInt(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

    if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
        return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

    int bits, val;
    do {
        bits = next(31);
        val = bits % n;
    } while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
    return val;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why does it treat the case where `n` is a power of two specially ? Is it just for performance ?
2. Why doest it reject numbers that `bits - val + (n-1) < 0` ?

Comment: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/java_util_random_algorithm.shtml#.VJAvuOp7jUY

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`next` generates random *bits*.

1. When `n` is a power of 2, a random integer in that range can be generated just by generating random bits (I assume that always generating 31 and throwing some away is for reproducibility). This code path is simpler and I guess it's a more commonly used case so it's worth making a special "fast path" for this case.
2. When `n` isn't a power of 2, it throws away numbers at the "top" of the range so that the random number is evenly distributed. E.g. imagine we had `n=3`, and imagine we were using 3 bits rather than 31 bits. So `bits` is a randomly generated number between 0 and 7. How can you generate a fair random number there? Answer: if `bits` is 6 or 7, we throw it away and generate a new one.

Comment: Thanks. How exactly do you know to throw away 6 and 7 in your example ?

Comment: We can check whether `bits - val + (n-1) >=8`; if so, that means the number came from the "last", incomplete copy of the range we want: `123123[12]`. Try it yourself, substitute `n=3` and the appropriate `bits` and `val`; you'll find that it's only `>=8` for `bits=6` and `bits=7`. The code is doing the same thing, it's just (ab)using integer overflow and so checking for `<0` rather than `>= INT_MAX + 1`.

Comment: Thank you. So why do we need to skip `bits - val + (n-1) < 0` (or as you say `bits - val + (n-1) >= INT_MAX + 1` ? What is so magic in this formula ?

Comment: `bits-val` gives you the "start" of the current "repeat"; in our example it will be 0 if `bits` was 0, 1 or 2, it will be 3 if `bits` was 3, 4, or 5, and it will be 6 if `bits` was 6 or 7. If that number plus `n-1` is >=8, it means that the current "repeat" doesn't "finish", it gets "cut off". Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did not get it but I will think about it.

Answer (score 10):

It does this in order to assure an uniform distribution of values between `0` and `n`. You might be tempted to do something like:

```
int x = rand.nextInt() % n;
```

but this will alter the distribution of values, unless n is a divisor of `2^31`, i.e. a power of 2. This is because the modulo operator would produce equivalence classes whose size is not the same.

For instance, let's suppose that `nextInt()` generates an integer between 0 and 6 inclusive and you want to draw 0,1 or 2. Easy, right?

```
int x = rand.nextInt() % 3;
```

No. Let's see why:

```
0 % 3 = 0
1 % 3 = 1
2 % 3 = 2
3 % 3 = 0
4 % 3 = 1
5 % 3 = 2
6 % 3 = 0
```

So you have 3 values that map on 0 and only 2 values that map on 1 and 2. You have a bias now, as 0 is more likely to be returned than 1 or 2.

As always, the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)) documents this behaviour:

> The hedge "approximately" is used in the foregoing description only
>   because the next method is only approximately an unbiased source of
>   independently chosen bits. If it were a perfect source of randomly
>   chosen bits, then the algorithm shown would choose int values from the
>   stated range with perfect uniformity.
>
> The algorithm is slightly tricky. **It rejects values that would result
>   in an uneven distribution** (due to the fact that 2^31 is not divisible
>   by n). The probability of a value being rejected depends on n. The
>   worst case is n=2^30+1, for which the probability of a reject is 1/2,
>   and the expected number of iterations before the loop terminates is 2.
>
> **The algorithm treats the case where n is a power of two specially**: it
>   returns the correct number of high-order bits from the underlying
>   pseudo-random number generator. In the absence of special treatment,
>   the correct number of low-order bits would be returned. Linear
>   congruential pseudo-random number generators such as the one
>   implemented by this class are known to have short periods in the
>   sequence of values of their low-order bits. Thus, this special case
>   greatly increases the length of the sequence of values returned by
>   successive calls to this method if n is a small power of two.

The emphasis is mine.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now that `randomInt() % n` is not uniformly  distributed. I wonder _why_ they throw away those `random % n` that  `random - random % n + (n-1) < 0`