# Confusing implementation of java.util.Random nextInt(int n)

Tags: java, random

I am trying to understand how *java.util.Random.nextInt(int n)* works and despite all the search and even debugging cannot completely understand the implementation.

It is the *while* loop that causes confusion:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)

```
int bits, val;
do {
    bits = next(31);
    val = bits % n;    
} while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
```

I realize this is supposed to address the modulo bias, but struggling to see how.

Question: how can possibly the expression

```
bits - val + (n-1)
```

be negative given that *bits* value is 31 bit long, i.e. *bits* is always positive? If *bits* is positive, *val* is always less than *bits* then *while* condition always stays > 0...

Comment: The `next(int n)` contract says the `n` low-order bits will be approximately random. It makes no assertion about the high-order bits. The high bit could be `0` or `1`. When it's `1` the value of `bits` is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been already addressed in [implementation-of-java-util-random-nextint.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27505355/implementation-of-java-util-random-nextint)

Basically, we have to drop some top-most elements for `bits` in the range `[0..2^31[` because they induce a non-uniform distribution

Mathematically we check :

```
bits - val + (n-1) >= 2^31
```

and could have wrote it as is if java had unsigned 32 bits integer arithmetics.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I should have tried harder  before asking!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the value of `n` in your calculation. Either `n` is negative, `bits - val -1 1 < n` or otherwise N is big enough to make the integer overflow and become a negative number.

Comment: Daniel, I should have copied the entire implementation of nextInt() here. The very first line of it checks that n is positive:
`if (n <= 0)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");`

Comment: Ok, that leaves the third option ;-)

Comment: Thank you, Daniel! Yeah, I completely missed the fact that overflow is part of the algorithm here.